# Can't copy file sshing, and coping files in a directory

Tags: python, ssh

I'm writing a small script to combine a number of steps but in the end i get :

```
scp: .: not a regular file
cp: cannot stat ‘/path/to/dir/': No such file or directory
```

I've checked that the directory does in fact exist that it's the same one contained in `dir_[0][:-1]`

here's the code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='get_f.py', description=__doc__)
parser.add_argument('-s', '--sub', help='particpant that you want to get dicoms for')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--user_acc', help='your user name')
parser.add_argument('-dd', '--dicom_dir', help='directory where dicoms are stored')
args = parser.parse_args()
sub = args.sub
user_acc = args.user_acc
dicom_dir = args.dicom_dir


subprocess.call(['ssh', '%s@sew.cwe.edu' % user_acc, '-t', 'sessionfinder',
     '--s', '%s' % sub, '>', '%s.txt' % sub, ';', 'sed',
     '-i', """'s/ /\\n/g'""", '%s.txt' % sub, ';', 'tail',
     '-2', '%s.txt' % sub,'|', 'head', '-1', '>', 'dir.txt', ';'
     'rm', '%s.txt' % sub])

if not os.path.isdir('%s//%s' % (dicom_dir, sub)):
    subprocess.call(['mkdir', '%s//%s' % (dicom_dir, sub)])

subprocess.call(['ssh', '%s@sew.cwe.edu' % user_acc, '-t', 'scp', 'dir.txt',
             '%s@suo.cwe.edu:%s//%s' % (user_acc, dicom_dir, sub), ';',
             'rm', 'dir.txt'])

if not os.path.isdir('%s//%s/dicom' % (dicom_dir, sub)):
    os.makedirs('%s//%s/dicom' % (dicom_dir, sub))

with open('%s//%s/dir.txt' % (dicom_dir, sub)) as f:
    dir_ = f.readlines()

subprocess.call(['scp', '%s@sew.cwe.edu:' % user_acc, dir_[0][:-1], 
                 '%s//%s/dicom/' % (dicom_dir, sub)])
```

I've tried adding `-r` and `-pr` to `scp` but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `dir_[0][:-1]` is not returning a string, but instead a list

```
user_acc = 'alan'
dir_ = [['src', 'main'],['opt', 'user']]
dicom_dir = '/var/tmp'
sub = '/subdir'

print ('scp', '%s@sew.cwe.edu:' % user_acc, dir_[0][:-1], '%s//%s/dicom/' % (dicom_dir, sub))
>> scp alan@sew.cwe.edu: ['src'] /var/tmp///subdir/dicom/

print ('scp', '%s@sew.cwe.edu:' % user_acc + ''.join(dir_[0][:-1]), '%s//%s/dicom/' % (dicom_dir, sub))
>> scp alan@sew.cwe.edu:src /var/tmp///subdir/dicom/
```

Try this:

```
subprocess.call(['scp', '%s@sew.cwe.edu:' % user_acc + ''.join(dir_[0][:-1]), '%s/%s/dicom/' % (dicom_dir, sub)])
```